# Problem Loading Custom phtml into CMS page

Tags: blocks, magento-1, cms, phtml

I am still fairly new to Magento and it's structure.

I have two custom PHTML files that show Featured & News products (one file) and recent Wordpress posts (second file). I had them in the `/dev/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html` directory which I have discovered is the core template location and could eventually be effected by a Magento update. They did load just fine when in this directory.

I moved them to my custom template directory (`/dev/app/design/frontend/default/rics/template/page/html` [rics being the name of our template]) and now they do not load.

These are being called in the default home page which is a CMS page in the Magento system. This is the block code that calls these pages,

```
{{block type="layerslider/layerslider" name="layerslider" template="layerslider/layerslider.phtml"}}

{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/featurednewproducts.phtml"}}

{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/newsrecentposts.phtml"}}
```

Here is the link to our development site - http://dev.flymasters.cliquecode.com/

The layerslider loads fine but the Featured & New products as well as the Recent News post do not load.

I am thinking it might be in the block "type" I have specified but am not certain.

If you need anymore information or code let me know.

I assume you mean the code of the two PHTML files. Here they are.

This is the Featured and New Products file (featurednewproducts.phtml)

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * @deprecated  after 1.4.0.0-alpha3
 */

/**
 * This template is for generic wrapper purposes, including ajax.updater loaded blocks
 *
 * Usage in layout xml files:
 * <block type="core/template" template="page/html/wrapper.phtml">
 *    <action method="setId"><id>some-custom-identificator</id></action>
 *
 *    <!-- optional -->
 *    <action method="setTag"><tag>span</tag></action> <!-- div is used if not specified -->
 *    <action method="setParams"><params>class="custom-class"</params></action>
 *
 *    <!-- insert wrapped blocks here -->
 * </block>
 */
?>
<div class="home-tabs-content">
    <div class="home-tabs">
        <div class="home-tabs-nav-wrapper">
            <ul class="tabs-nav">
                <li class="tab-nav active" data-toid="1">Featured Products</li>
                <li class="tab-nav" data-toid="2">New Products</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-content-wrapper">
            <div class="content-tab active" id='tab1' style="background-color:#fff !important;">
                <?php
                $fCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(126);
                $fProducts = $fCat->getProductCollection()->setPageSize(4)->setCurPage(1)->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
                if(count($fProducts) > 0):
                    ?>
                    <a href="/featured.html" class="view-all">View All Featured Items</a>
                    <ul class="tabs-products-ul">
                        <?php
                        foreach($fProducts as $fProduct):
                            ?>
                            <li class="products-li">
                                <div class="products-li-content-wrapper"><?php //echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/item1.jpg') ?>
                                    <div class="products-li-img-wrapper"><a href="<?= $fProduct->getUrlPath(); ?>"><img src="<?= $fProduct->getImageUrl(); ?>" class="products-li-img"/></a></div>
                                    <div class="products-li-content">
                                        <p class="products-li-title"><a href="<?= $fProduct->getUrlPath(); ?>" class="products-li-title"><?= $fProduct->getName(); ?></d></p>
                                        <p class="products-li-price" class="products-li-title"><?= Mage::helper('core')->currency($fProduct->getPrice()); ?></p>
                                        <a href="<?= $fProduct->getUrlPath(); ?>" class="products-li-link">VIEW</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="content-tab" id='tab2' style="background-color:#fff !important;">
                <?php
                $nCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(127);
                $nProducts = $nCat->getProductCollection()->setPageSize(4)->setCurPage(1)->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
                if(count($nProducts) > 0):
                    ?>
                    <a href="/new.html" class="view-all">View All New Items</a>
                    <ul class="tabs-products-ul">
                        <?php
                        foreach($nProducts as $nProduct):
                            ?>
                            <li class="products-li">
                                <div class="products-li-content-wrapper"><?php //echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/item1.jpg') ?>
                                    <div class="products-li-img-wrapper"><a href="<?= $nProduct->getUrlPath(); ?>"><img src="<?= $nProduct->getImageUrl(); ?>" class="products-li-img"/></a></div>
                                    <div class="products-li-content">
                                        <p class="products-li-title"><a href="<?= $nProduct->getUrlPath(); ?>" class="products-li-title"><?= $nProduct->getName(); ?></a></p>
                                        <p class="products-li-price" class="products-li-title"><?= Mage::helper('core')->currency($nProduct->getPrice()); ?></p>
                                        <a href="<?= $nProduct->getUrlPath(); ?>" class="products-li-link">VIEW</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Recent blog post file (newsrecentposts.phtml)

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * @deprecated  after 1.4.0.0-alpha3
 */

/**
 * This template is for generic wrapper purposes, including ajax.updater loaded blocks
 *
 * Usage in layout xml files:
 * <block type="core/template" template="page/html/wrapper.phtml">
 *    <action method="setId"><id>some-custom-identificator</id></action>
 *
 *    <!-- optional -->
 *    <action method="setTag"><tag>span</tag></action> <!-- div is used if not specified -->
 *    <action method="setParams"><params>class="custom-class"</params></action>
 *
 *    <!-- insert wrapped blocks here -->
 * </block>
 */
?>
<div class="home-tabs-content">
    <div class="home-tabs"> 
        <div class="home-news-wrapper">
            <div class="home-news-block">

                <div class="col-sm-3 news-image-left-link-wrapper">
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('page/html/lefthandlinks.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-9 news-content-wrapper">
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="home-news">Latest News</h2>
                    </div>
                <?php       
                    $posts = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')->addPostTypeFilter('post')
                        ->addIsViewableFilter()
                        ->addCategoryIdFilter(3)
                        ->setPageSize(5)
                        ->load();
                    if(!empty($posts)){         
                        foreach($posts as $post):
                ?>
                            <div>
                                <?php // $post is already defined ?>
                                <?php if ($featuredImage = $post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $featuredImage->getAvailableImage() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?>" style="float: left; margin: 8px; width: 120px; height: 120px;" /></a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <span class="news-date"><?php echo $post->getPostDate() ?></span>
                                <h3 class="news-title news-li-title">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>">
                                        <?php echo $post->getPostTitle() ?>
                                    </a>
                                </h3>
                                <span class="news-content"><?php echo $post->getPostExcerpt(50) ?> ... <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>">Read More</a></span>
                                <span class="bottom-liner"></span>
                                <p style="text-align: center;">
                                    <br><img src="http://dev.flymasters.cliquecode.com/media/wysiwyg/line_DblGreenHorz.jpg" width="710" height="3" />
                                </p>

                            </div>
                    <?php
                        endforeach;
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 news-image-right-link-wrapper">
                    <img src="http://dev.flymasters.cliquecode.com/media/wysiwyg/GrizzlyKing.jpg" width="130" height="130" />
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

If there is information in any other files you need let me know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes you are right this problem with block type from where you written this two phtml block please provide full code so we can help you

Comment: I assume you mean the code of the two PHTML files. Here they are.

Comment: Updated original question with the code from the two files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue had to do with rights. Once I set permission to 775 on each of the files it started working fine.